# Git push command doesn't display "Compare & pull request" in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am trying to understand the version control system GitHub and git commands. In particular i
want to understand push and pull request concept.

I have followed the steps described in [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/create-pull-request-github) to get "Compare & pull request" button in GitHub.

I have first forked repository https://github.com/kedark3/demo.

Then I have executed the following steps:

1. Cloned repo: `git clone https://github.com/rejkid-tester/Demo.git` to my local folder.
2. Created new_branch: `git branch new_branch`
3. Switched to new_branch: `git switch new_branch`
4. Changed the content of "test" file in repo using notepad.exe editor

Then I executed three more commands:

a) `git add .`
b) `git commit -m "Test"`
c) `git push origin new_branch`

After this I was expecting to see "Compare & pull request" button in GitHub in the browser.
I didn't get any errors but I also didn't see the button "Compare & pull request".

Which step have I missed to get what I want.

PS C:\workspace\GITTest\Demo> git push origin new_branch

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 334 bytes | 334.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'new_branch' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/rejkid-tester/Demo/pull/new/new_branch
remote:
To https://github.com/rejkid-tester/Demo.git
 * [new branch]      new_branch -> new_branch
```

PS C:\workspace\GITTest\Demo> git config --list

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
core.editor="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
user.email=rejkid@gmail.com
user.name=rejkid-tester
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/rejkid-tester/Demo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.upstream.url=https://github.com/kedark3/demo
remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Comment: Did you try manually creating the pull request on GitHub? Does your branch appear on your repo? The button you're looking for is just a facility.

Comment: It works manually but I want to see this "Compare & pull request"  button regularly.

Comment: `new_branch` doesn't show up on the github repo you mention. Check if the remote is the one you think (run `git remote -v` and check the urls), check whether your `git push` command was succesful (since `git push` always outputs something in the terminal, it is easy to overlook an error message)

Comment: Is your github username `rejkid-tester`? If not, then your `git push` command would give an error because you are not authorized to push to a repo owned by this user. If this is in fact your user name, then you didn't successfully push the branch because it isn't there. You probably didn't authenticate correctly with github before pushing.

Comment: Please see my original post where I have included the output from 'git push origin new_branch' and ` git config --list`.